# Custom Hibernate POJO field from Aggregate of Child Object fields

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have a Parent Class A, which has a set of Child classes B, how can I create a new field within the Parent Class that is an aggregate of one of the childs A fields.  For example, suppose A has 10 child B objects which each have some Integer field.  How can I create a field in A that is just the maximum of these fields. I was hoping to have this field populated automatically during mapping. Is this possible?  Am I approaching this problem in a wrong direction?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of derived property in this sense in JPA. Options are:

- Just  create method that makes needed calculation (no dependency to specific JPA provider).
- Use Hibernate's [@Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/mapping/Formula.html). Argument can be as complex SQL as needed.